# How to make HtmlEditor default text to empty in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, html-editor

I am having HTMLEditor, in that htmleditor by default i am getting `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` text. So when ever i am finding length in editor ,  minimum i am getting 62. But how to know whether HTMLEditor is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

Just set initial htmlText argument to an empty string

```
@FXML
HTMLText text;

private void initialize() {
    text.setHtmlText("");
}
```

Or directly in FXML file

```
<HTMLEditor htmlText=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and practical way is to clear those texts

```
htmleditor.getHtmlText()
       .replace("<html><head></head><body>", "")
       .replace("</body></html>", "")
       .isEmpty();
```

However if you want a real emptiness of html content then it is a little hard. Search the net with "java html strip tag" keywords.